# ActiveX preventing live site from loading background image

Tags: jquery, activex

I have a website that works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but every few times I open it in IE, the background image doesn't load without me manually allowing activex to run.  Everything else loads but the background image.

Once I've allowed it, the background image loads fine.  If I don't allow it, the background is black.  However, if I refresh the page, the background image loads without the activex warning.

I've done an extensive Google search looking for what the issue might be, but the only thing I can find is that this is frequently an issue when loading a local site.  However, my site (www.jesselaplante.com) is live.

I would include code, but I'm not at all sure what part might be causing the problem.  Obviously, I don't want clients to have to allow activex when they come to my site and it's pretty important that the background image loads.

Answer (score 1):

Works in my IE (9.0.10) without prompting me for ActiveX. However, in FireBug console I noticed you get an error when the page loads:

NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported

Comment: Thanks for checking this out!  I think I was on the wrong track with ActiveX.  I'm guessing the issue probably has more to do with a little bit of jQuery I used to patch something up.  Back to the classroom....